# Data migration MS SQL to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

What is the best way to migrate data from MS SQL database to oracle database? I have an idea to use Spring batch. Any other best solutions?? Pls advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Migrate usually means 'a once off load' whereas spring batch (which I just looked up) is all about running regular batch jobs. YOur issue is not finding tools to transfer the data, the issue is for example hand-coverting the T-SQL found in views, stored procedures, functions into the Oracle equivalent.

Comment: @ Asha Perera, Please excuse me for asking a private question here. Have you attended IJTS ? I guess I know you.

Comment: @Kushan Randima, Yes. I was in Advance Java Devloper Cls also. I remember Kushan was in our team. Is that you? :-)

Comment: @AshaPerera,Yeah.. I think so. I will be able to find you on FB and I will send you a friend request. I'm a .NET developer, but I will assist U in this context. Btw... it's a pleasure to meet a old friend :-)

Comment: @AshaPerera, I hope you want to do this using JAVA. Is it?

Comment: There is a tool to migrate MS SQL to Oracle:

Use this link :-http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

If you want to see the instructions, use this video 
 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9507668/Data%20migration%20MS%20SQL%20to%20Oracle.swf

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm  and http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLServerMigration/SQLServerMigration.htm

Comment: @KushanRandima Thanks Kushan, I'll go through the tutrials. :-)